# Explaining switch of research interests in Statement of Purpose

Tags: graduate-school, statement-of-purpose

For most of my Masters studies, I worked in the area of Quantum computation and wrote my thesis on that. But following that, I lost my interest and switched to Computer Vision and worked as an intern for a few months. Now I plan to pursue a PhD in the field of Computer Vision even though my Masters thesis was on a different topic. How should I convince the admission committee about this switch ?

I had published 2 papers while working on Quantum computations (one from my Thesis and another one as a student job) and 1 in Computer Vision from my internship. But I was not interested in Quantum computations because it consisted mostly coding and there was no hardware to work on (at least in my university). Whereas computer vision is a branch I am very comfortable with since I directly get to see the impact of the changes in algorithm visually. I also have very good grades in the area related to computer vision. But I cannot really frame a convincing story as "visual feedback" is not enough concrete to convince a potential guide.

Please give me your inputs. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to convince the admission committee about the switch.

You do have to convince the admission committee that you are able to complete a PhD in Computer Vision.

Work out what skills will be needed, and present your evidence that you have those skills.

Work out what knowledge will be needed as a prerequisite, and present your evidence that you have that knowledge.

Work out what the other pre-requisities are (funding, contributing to the internal life of the department, whatever), and present the evidence for that too.